# Images specified in css not displayed

Tags: css, hosting

I decided to move from shared hosting to a dedicated server but things aren't working as expected. Unfortunately the images do not load.
I load images from php and css files. When I uploaded all the images (Images folder) to the server, all of them have permission 600 even if the folder has 777. I figured out that when I set the permission of an image to 644 then those images that are displayed in the .php files appear:

```
<img src="Images/good.png" class="feature" alt="tick"/>
```

However, those that are specified in the .css files, don't:

```
background-image:url('Images/bcg_opt.png');
```

How can I solve this?

Ps: The .css file is in the same folder as the .php file. So the hierarchy is sg like this:

```
Images
index.php
design.css
```

Comment: It should work try to give the full path.

Answer (score 1):

While uploading the files to server sometimes extension changes, like from .jpg to .JPG, and this affects the code in displaying the images....
Your code is perfect otherwise..
You should look for this error in server....